# HTTP/2 shared settings for both endpoints?

Tags: http2

When the connection starts, image the following scenario:

The **client** sends the preface and the **server** sends a SETTINGS frame. It sets `1` to `16384` and `3` to `1000` (those numbers have no special meaning, just for illustration), then the clients sends it's SETTINGS frame with the setting `1`=`8192` and `2`=`1`.

Now, are there two seperate mappings for the settings? So a local and remote one?

Like local=[`1`=`16384`, `3`=`1000`] and remote=[`1`=`8192`, `2`=`1`]
or do they share one map for the settings?

Like settings=[`1`=`8192`, `2`=`1`, `3`=`1000`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 7540, section 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.5) states that:

> SETTINGS parameters are not negotiated; they describe characteristics of the sending peer, which are used by the receiving peer.  Different values for the same parameter can be advertised by each peer.

Your particular example mentions settings key 1, which corresponds to SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE, which has a particular handling that is specified also in [RFC 7541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541).

In general, local and remote peers maintain separate mappings for the settings, and some are only meaningful (or have slightly different semantic) for one peer only.

For example, a server may inform a client that it won't accept more than 1024 concurrent streams (key 3, SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS), but it's unlikely that a client would inform a server of this value in typical deployments

Comment: Ok thanks, now based on your answer, my second question is: When the client sends a SETTINGS frame and there are already streams open, will the window size of **all** active streams be updated or only of those, that are client- or server-initiated?

Comment: Assuming that the SETTINGS frame contains a SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE, then **all** active streams will be updated, and all future streams. In typical deployments there are no server-initiated streams; pushed streams act like a "synthetic" client-initiated stream. The reference is [this section](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-6.9.2).